# Sqlparameter should be assigned Exception and if I assigned so,there is violation of primary key constraint exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have to insert the field values but not the id which is a primary key and set identity(1,1). Stored Procedure is also added at the bottom.

```
protected void save_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con = new SqlConnection(s);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("employeedtl", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =      TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empage", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empjoindate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empproject", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empmobile", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Int64.Parse(TextBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empemail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@select", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id"); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Label1.Text = "Inserted Successfully";
        con.Close();
        bindGrid(GridView1);

}

ALTER procedure [dbo].[employeedtl](@select int,@empid int,@empname varchar(50),@empage int,@empaddress varchar(max),@empjoindate varchar(50),@empproject varchar(50),@empmobile bigint,@empemail varchar(max))
    as
    begin
    if @select=1
    begin
    if Exists(select * from EmployeeDB where Empid=@empid)      
    begin
     update EmployeeDB set [EmpId]=@empid,[EmpName]=@empname,[EmpAge]=@empage,[EmpAddress]=@empaddress,[EmpJoin]=@empjoindate,[EmpProj]=@empproject,[EmpMobile]=@empmobile,[EmpEmail]=@empemail where Empid=@empid
     end
     else 
     begin
     insert into EmployeeDB(EmpId,EmpName,EmpAge,EmpJoin,EmpAddress,EmpProj,EmpMobile,EmpEmail) values(@empid,@empname,@empage,@empaddress,@empjoindate,@empproject,@empmobile,@empemail)
     end
     end
     else if @select=2
     begin
     delete from EmployeeDB where EmpId=@empid
     end
    end
```

Comment: remove parameter for id and accordingly on insert query

Comment: Post the stored procedure's code *in the question text*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@id");` // remove this
2. Remove @id in `ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Employeetl`
3. Remove id in insert `INSERT INTO EmployeeDB(EmpName, . . . )`

Answer (score 0):

Alter your stored procedure

```
// SQL Server stored procedure
alter storedprocedure employeedtl (
    @id int = null,
    @empname nvarchar(50) = null,
    .
    .
    .
     )

// in .Net remove this line
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id");
```

Comment: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'keshav.dbo.EmployeeDB'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT f

Comment: insert into  keshav.dbo.EmployeeDB (empname,empid,empage,empaddress,empjoindate,empproject,empmobile,empemail,select)
values (@empname,@empid,@empage,@empaddress,@empjoindate,@empproject,@empmobile,@empemail,@select)   remove id which is Autoincrement id from the insert query

Answer (score 0):

Need two changes

1. Pass value to `@id` parameter in code

   ```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = xxx;
   ```
2. Alter stored procedure to update INSERT Command

   ```
   INSERT INTO EMPTable(id,empname,empid,empage,empaddress,empjoindate,empproject,empm‌​obile,empemail,selec‌​t) values (@empname,@empid,@empage,@empaddress,@empjoindate,@empprojec‌​t,@empmobile,@empema‌​il,@select)
                 -------^
   ```

   remove this ID column from INSERT with its value `@id`